# Prove that $\{ x \mid P(x) \} \subseteq \{ x \mid P(x) \lor Q(x) \}$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am unsure how to start this problem.  I am new to proofs and I have a general idea but am unsure how to fully implement it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Prove that $\{ x \mid P(x) \} \subseteq \{ x \mid P(x) \lor Q(x) \}$

My General Idea:

Would I need to use the definition of $\subseteq$ which is $(\forall x)(x\in A \to x\in B)$?

Comment: Additionally to definition It's enough to know, that for logical expressions $p \rightarrow p \lor q$ is tautology.

Comment: Exactly; you have to show that $x \in \{ x \mid P(x) \} \to x \in \{  x \mid P(x) \lor Q(x) \}$. But what does it mean  $x \in \{ x \mid P(x) \}$ ? It means: $P(x)$.

Comment: Please, user the proper formula editor to write formulas...

Comment: @RyanG Saying $x$ is "an arbitrary element" doesn't make much sense - element of what? The argument actually begins just "Suppose $x\in A$.

Comment: Yes, simplest to just start with "Let $x∈A$" rather than "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A.$"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. More precisely, the conclusion follows from:

\begin{align*}
x\in\{x\mid P(x)\}&\Rightarrow P(x)\\
&\Rightarrow P(x)\vee Q(x)\\
&\Rightarrow x\in\{x\mid P(x)\vee Q(x)\}.
\end{align*}